# Is there another way to specify exactly which columns or rows to be selected for preprocessing(cleaning data frame)?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

Firstly, I have a dataset like the following:

```
Date Time        Open  ...   Adj Close      Volume

0       1/3/2017 0:00  225.039993  ...  208.895447         NaN

1       1/4/2017 0:00  225.619995  ...  210.138245  78744400.0

...
```

I wonder how to put **columns' lable** in the variable **imputer**.

But, I do not want to  use iloc or loc.

When I run the code=  Volume can not be iterated .

In addition,   [1]: https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html

```
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\v\Desktop\sp500.csv")
    df1 = df1.replace(nan,1)
    # retrieve the numpy array
    values =df1.values
    # define the imputer
    imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=1, strategy='mean', column= Volume)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of specifying the column name given the Dataframe (df). You can pass `df1.Volume` or `df1['Volume']` in the SimpleImputer method

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=1, strategy='mean', column= df1.Volume)
```

OR

```
Imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=1, strategy='mean', column= df1['Volume'])
```

Comment: Thanks. But the error raises: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: @John for which line you are getting the error and also this is a different error and seems some issue with how you are handling the data. You can open a new question specific to that